# How can I find the smallest number between variables?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have 4 variables which they contain some values.

I have already convert them in numbers with `CDbl`.

So I have something like that:

```
var1=CDbl(str1)
var2=CDbl(str2)
var3=CDbl(str3)
var4=CDbl(str4)
```

How can I find the smallest number between var1, var2, var3 and var4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works. You just have to pass the values as an array.

```
Function FindSmallest(arr)
    out = arr(0)
    For i = 1 to UBound(arr)
        If out > arr(i) Then
            out = arr(i)
        End If
    Next
    FindSmallest = out
End Function

WScript.Echo FindSmallest(Array(var1,var2,var3,var4))
```

Comment: Great answer, you did their homework for them and they didn’t even have to try. So, basically they’ve learned nothing except posting a quick one liner on [so] will do their work for them.